# Non linear fit with shared parameters and a known variable

Tags: fitting, nonlinear

I am new to Mathematica and I am able to do only basic stuff.

Here is the situation: I have some datasets (2 in the following for simplicity) that I would like to fit.
The function that I am trying to fit is the following:

```
(* Define the general function *)
f[x_, a_, b_, c_, n_] := Exp[-n*x (a + b*n + c*n*n)];
```

Where **a,b,c** are shared parameters between the datasets and **n** is known (i.e. 10 for the first dataset and 20 for the second dataset).

I am able to fit a single (or even both) dataset with a **n**:

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data10, 
   f[x, a, b, c, 10}], {{a, 0}, {b, 0}, {c, 0}}, x, 
   MaxIterations -> 10000];
```

But I am not able to find a solution for variable **ns** and thus to fit all the datasets with the appropriate **n**.
I am trying the following with no success:

```
data = Join[data10, data20];
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, 
       f[x, a, b, c, {10, 20}], {{a, 0}, {b, 0}, {c, 0}}, x, 
       MaxIterations -> 10000];
```

I am assuming that the procedure is correct but I am not sure and I am opened to other solutions.

Here is the data in case you might need it:

```
data10 = {{1, 1}, {2, 0.933}, {3, 0.88}, {4, 0.84}, {5, 0.8}, {6, 
    0.773}, {7, 0.733}, {8, 0.68}, {9, 0.667}, {10, 0.64}, {11, 
    0.64}, {12, 0.64}, {13, 0.64}, {14, 0.613}, {15, 0.613}, {16, 
    0.587}, {17, 0.573}, {18, 0.573}, {19, 0.56}, {20, 0.547}, {21, 
    0.533}, {22, 0.493}, {23, 0.48}, {24, 0.453}, {25, 0.453}, {26, 
    0.427}, {27, 0.413}, {28, 0.4}, {29, 0.4}, {30, 0.373}, {31, 
    0.347}, {32, 0.333}, {33, 0.333}, {34, 0.32}, {35, 0.32}, {36, 
    0.32}, {37, 0.307}, {38, 0.293}, {39, 0.28}, {40, 0.28}, {41, 
    0.28}, {42, 0.253}, {43, 0.227}, {44, 0.213}, {45, 0.213}, {46, 
    0.187}, {47, 0.187}, {48, 0.16}, {49, 0.16}, {50, 0.147}, {51, 
    0.147}, {52, 0.147}, {53, 0.147}, {54, 0.147}, {55, 0.147}, {56, 
    0.147}, {57, 0.12}, {58, 0.107}, {59, 0.107}, {60, 0.0933}, {61, 
    0.0933}, {62, 0.0933}, {63, 0.0933}, {64, 0.0933}, {65, 
    0.08}, {66, 0.08}, {67, 0.08}, {68, 0.0667}, {69, 0.0533}, {70, 
    0.0533}, {71, 0.0533}, {72, 0.0533}, {73, 0.0533}, {74, 
    0.0533}, {75, 0.0533}, {76, 0.0533}, {77, 0.0533}, {78, 
    0.0533}, {79, 0.0533}, {80, 0.0533}, {81, 0.0533}, {82, 
    0.0533}, {83, 0.0533}, {84, 0.0533}, {85, 0.0533}, {86, 
    0.0533}, {87, 0.0533}, {88, 0.0533}, {89, 0.04}, {90, 0.04}, {91, 
    0.04}, {92, 0.04}, {93, 0.04}, {94, 0.0267}, {95, 0.0267}, {96, 
    0.0267}, {97, 0.0267}, {98, 0.0267}, {99, 0.0267}, {100, 0.0267}};

data20 = {{1, 1.}, {2, 0.84}, {3, 0.787}, {4, 0.773}, {5, 0.693}, {6, 
    0.653}, {7, 0.613}, {8, 0.6}, {9, 0.547}, {10, 0.533}, {11, 
    0.493}, {12, 0.44}, {13, 0.413}, {14, 0.413}, {15, 0.387}, {16, 
    0.373}, {17, 0.36}, {18, 0.347}, {19, 0.333}, {20, 0.333}, {21, 
    0.32}, {22, 0.28}, {23, 0.267}, {24, 0.24}, {25, 0.213}, {26, 
    0.2}, {27, 0.187}, {28, 0.187}, {29, 0.187}, {30, 0.16}, {31, 
    0.147}, {32, 0.12}, {33, 0.12}, {34, 0.12}, {35, 0.107}, {36, 
    0.08}, {37, 0.0667}, {38, 0.0667}, {39, 0.0667}, {40, 
    0.0667}, {41, 0.0267}, {42, 0.0267}, {43, 0.0267}, {44, 
    0.0267}, {45, 0.0267}, {46, 0.0267}, {47, 0.0267}, {48, 
    0.0133}, {49, 0.0133}, {50, 0.0133}, {51, 0.0133}, {52, 
    0.0133}, {53, 0.0133}, {54, 0.0133}, {55, 0.0133}, {56, 0.}, {57, 
    0.}, {58, 0.}, {59, 0.}, {60, 0.}, {61, 0.}, {62, 0.}, {63, 
    0.}, {64, 0.}, {65, 0.}, {66, 0.}, {67, 0.}, {68, 0.}, {69, 
    0.}, {70, 0.}, {71, 0.}, {72, 0.}, {73, 0.}, {74, 0.}, {75, 
    0.}, {76, 0.}, {77, 0.}, {78, 0.}, {79, 0.}, {80, 0.}, {81, 
    0.}, {82, 0.}, {83, 0.}, {84, 0.}, {85, 0.}, {86, 0.}, {87, 
    0.}, {88, 0.}, {89, 0.}, {90, 0.}, {91, 0.}, {92, 0.}, {93, 
    0.}, {94, 0.}, {95, 0.}, {96, 0.}, {97, 0.}, {98, 0.}, {99, 
    0.}, {100, 0.}};
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
NonlinearModelFit[
 Join[{#1, 10, #2} & @@@ data10, {#1, 20, #2} & @@@ data20],
 f[x, a, b, c, n],
 {{a, 0}, {b, 0}, {c, 0}},
 {x, n}
]
```

The idea is to just add `n` as an extra independent variable, since it is known in advance.

Alternatively, you can use this [resource function](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/MultiNonlinearModelFit):

```
ResourceFunction["MultiNonlinearModelFit"][
 {data10, data20},
 {f[x, a, b, c, 10], f[x, a, b, c, 20]},
 {{a, 0}, {b, 0}, {c, 0}},
 x
]
```

Comment: Thanks, the first one solved my problem. Anyway, I've tried to use MultiNonlinearModelFit but it does not give any output but the call itself. I have also tried to replicate one of the examples but with no success. Maybe I am using a too old version of mathematica(v9.0) ?

Comment: Ah, yes. `ResourceFunction`s are only supported from version 11 and up. You should be able to download the notebook from the webpage and see the source code of the function and copy it out, though. The notebook may not format correctly, but I think it might work.